# ScrollMagic animation is not working in windows laptop or android phone

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, scrollmagic

I have designed this page http://kodeandgraphics.com/dragoran2802/hello.html Actually I have copied the all the source files in html. The web page animation is working fine in MAC machines but not on windows or android phones. I need help to get understand where is the problem. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check your console for errors. Whole JavaScript stopped working because `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the console is empty http://prntscr.com/roe40j

Comment: I have checked the console error now i am using this js file and its third party link
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
    <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2429/4551/t/29/assets/main.min.js?v=8284646779484599834" defer="defer"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2429/4551/t/29/assets/main.min.js?v=8284646779484599834"></script><![endif]-->